# Changing select value to dynamically added option causes value = ""

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a `select` that I can't programmatically change. The `select` starts with only one `option`:

Initial HTML:

```
  <select id="clients" name="client">
    <option>Existing Clients...</option>
  </select>
```

Then I GET the clients and add them to the `select`:

```
getClients();

function getClients() {
  $.get('ajax/get-clients.php')
    .done(function(response) {
      for (let client of JSON.parse(response)) {
        addClientOption(client.id, client.company_name);
      }
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }

function addClientOption(id, name) {
  let newOption = document.createElement('option');

  newOption.value = parseInt(id);
  newOption.text = name;
  document.getElementById('clients').appendChild(newOption);
}
```

It now has some options:

```
<select id="clients" name="client">
  <option>Existing Clients...</option>
  <option value="6">Number1</option>
  <option value="77">SecondROUND</option>
  <option value="14">Whips Dat Llama</option>
</select>
```

So I try to change its value:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('clients').value); // =>"Existing Clients..."
document.getElementById('clients').value = 6;          // expecting "Number1"
console.log(document.getElementById('clients').value); // =>""

// And the select still shows the "Existing Clients..." option.
```

I tried hard coding the `options` into the `select` and it works as expected. Dynamically adding them seems to be the issue. I can come up with a workaround, but can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: It works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/3ekvaxxr/3/

Comment: Are you sure you're assigning to `.value` after the AJAX response is received? Where is that assignment in the code?

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the fiddle. The assignment is right after the call to getClients(). It looks like: `$(function() { getClients(); document.getElementById('clients').value = 6; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the options using AJAX, which is asynchronous. You have to wait for the response before you assign to `.value`, otherwise the option with that value won't exist. So it needs to be done in the `getClients` callback function.

```
function getClients() {
  $.get('ajax/get-clients.php')
    .done(function(response) {
      for (let client of JSON.parse(response)) {
        addClientOption(client.id, client.company_name);
      }
      document.getElementById('clients').value = 6;
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Comment: So it's proceeding to the next instruction (the .value assignment) before the AJAX finishes? Oooooooh of course. 'Cause that's how AJAX works. Ha. Great thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set the value of the `<select>`-field, but you should assign an attribute `selected` to the `option`-field you want to select.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: Assigning to `.value` of the `<select>` should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: `document.getElementById('clients').options[1].selected = true; //=> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined`